# Android Textview width in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm writing a chat program. In chat activity, my sent and received messages are displaying with EditTexts like bubbles. I want to set my width of edittexts with the same width of its messages. In my code, when message is created, new edittexts are being created programmatically in the relativelayout. How can I set it?

```
public void sendmyMessage(String msg){
    // mRR is my RelativeLayout
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    EditText e = new EditText(mRR.getContext());
    e.setId(arr.size()+2);
    e.setEnabled(false);
    e.setFocusable(false);
    e.setClickable(false);
    e.setText(msg);
    e.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
    e.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    e.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
    e.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#080808"));

    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(setDp(150, e.getContext()),RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    params.setMargins(0, setDp(8, e.getContext()), 0, 0);
    if(arr.isEmpty()){
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    }else{
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,arr.get(arr.size()-1).getId());
    }
    Spannable str = e.getText();
    str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    e.setLayoutParams(params);
    e.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mytext);
    arr.add(e);
    mRR.addView(e);

}
```

The function is this. I don't want to set the width fixsize. What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this..?

```
editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: i actually now understood that wrapcontent.. how stupid me :), thanks